# Add new column with number of duplicated in two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello I have a dataframe such as :

```
COL1 COL2 
SP1  A
SP1  A
SP1  B
SP2  A
SP2  C
SP2  D
SP3  E
SP4  B
SP4  B
SP4  B
```

And I would like to change it as :

```
COL1 Value COL2 
SP1  2     A
SP1  1     B
SP2  1     A
SP2  1     C
SP2  1     D
SP3  1     E
SP4  3     B
```

Where the column `Value` is the number of duplicated `c('COL1','COL2')`

Does someone have an idea in R?

Here are the exemple data :

```
structure(list(COL1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("SP1", "SP2", "SP3", "SP4"), class = "factor"), 
    COL2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Is it one or two columns? There is only one column in your last data example.

Comment: SOrry, I edited the dput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) and [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/) from [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# your data
data <- structure(
  list(COL1.COL2 =
         structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L),
                   .Label = c("SP1  A", "SP1  B", "SP2  A", "SP2  C", "SP2  D", "SP3  E", "SP4  B"),
                   class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

data <- as_tibble(data)

# split Col1.Col2 into two columns
data <- data %>%
  separate(COL1.COL2, c("COL1", "COL2"))

# add column "Value"
result <- data %>%
  group_by(COL1, COL2) %>%
  summarise(Value = n())

result
```

or shorter:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- structure(
  list(COL1.COL2 =
         structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L),
                   .Label = c("SP1  A", "SP1  B", "SP2  A", "SP2  C", "SP2  D", "SP3  E", "SP4  B"),
                   class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

result <- data %>%
  separate(COL1.COL2, c("COL1", "COL2")) %>%
  group_by(COL1, COL2) %>%
  summarise(Value = n())

result
```

Answer (score 2):

using `library(data.table)`

```
setDT(dt)
dt[, .(value=.N), .(COL1,COL2)]

#    COL1 COL2 value
# 1:  SP1    A     2
# 2:  SP1    B     1
# 3:  SP2    A     1
# 4:  SP2    C     1
# 5:  SP2    D     1
# 6:  SP3    E     1
# 7:  SP4    B     3
```

Comment: Should note that this prints the results, but does not modify the `data.frame` as `dt` still returns the original data.

Comment: Not sure what your point is @manotheshark.  if you want to store the answer you just use assignment (`<-`) - the same applies to all the answers here.

Answer (score 1):

This might do with `interaction` + `table`:

```r
res <- table(interaction(dat$COL1, dat$COL2, drop = TRUE, sep = "~~"))
res <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(res), "~~")), c(res))
dimnames(res) <- list(1:NROW(res), c(colnames(dat), "Value"))
res
#R>   COL1 COL2 Value
#R> 1  SP1    A     2
#R> 2  SP2    A     1
#R> 3  SP1    B     1
#R> 4  SP4    B     3
#R> 5  SP2    C     1
#R> 6  SP2    D     1
#R> 7  SP3    E     1
```

You can change `sep` if `"~~"` is somewhere in some of the factors. This extends to more factor variables than two by adding another argument to `interaction`.

You can also just use `table` like this:

```r
res <- table(dat$COL1, dat$COL2)
keep <- which(res > 0) - 1L
data.frame(COl1 = rownames(res)[keep %% NROW(res) + 1L], 
           COL2 = colnames(res)[floor(keep / NCOL(res)) + 1L],
           Values = res[keep + 1L])
#R>   COl1 COL2 Values
#R> 1  SP1    A      2
#R> 2  SP2    A      1
#R> 3  SP1    A      1
#R> 4  SP4    B      3
#R> 5  SP2    B      1
#R> 6  SP2    C      1
#R> 7  SP3    D      1
```

The former is presumably more efficient when there are many factor levels. You can use `sort` if you want to get the data into the order you show.

Answer (score 1):

First using `unique` to remove any duplicated items.  Then using `lapply` to iterate unique data to count the number of rows that match from original data.  Example data stored in `df1`

```
df2 <- unique(df1)
df2$Value <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(df2)),
                    function(x) nrow(df1[df1$COL1 == df2$COL1[x] & df1$COL2 == df2$COL2[x], ]))

> df2
  COL1 COL2 Value
1  SP1    A     2
3  SP1    B     1
4  SP2    A     1
5  SP2    C     1
6  SP2    D     1
7  SP3    E     1
8  SP4    B     3
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(Value ~ ., cbind(df, Value = 1), sum)
  COL1 COL2 Value
1  SP1    A     2
2  SP2    A     1
3  SP1    B     1
4  SP4    B     3
5  SP2    C     1
6  SP2    D     1
7  SP3    E     1
```